# How to automatically start a cloud windows instance periodically?

Tags: windows, azure, cloud, automation

I have zero experience with windows server management, azure, etc. and therefore asking for an advice here.

There exist an automation script that needs to be executed every N days, it takes ~10 minutes to run, and the machine should be halted afterwards. Automation relies on screen capture, so it can not be just a remote windows shell. I am not using windows on any of my machines and therfore wonder if it can be done for cheap with azure, or aws, or in some other cheap way, since the running time of this job would be something as little as 1h/month with very little traffic and disk usage, so I suppose it should not cost much to set up.

I could use a nano aws instance with a cron job that uses azure api or something like that, of course, but it seems like something not very reliable. I want to be pretty sure that this automation script actually runs periodically.

I wonder if azure or other cloud providers provide "start this windows cloud instance from this image every X days and wait for it to halt" functionality? Or windows server installations can do that by themselves somehow?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Start/Stop VMs during off-hours solution in Azure Automation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management)